# Static variable becomes zero

Tags: blackberry, java-me, static

I have the following code:

```
public static int smsCount = 0 ;

public void startListener()
{
    SendListener smsListener;
    smsListener = new SendListener() {

        public boolean sendMessage(Message message) {
            ++smsCount;
            return true;
        }
    };

    SMS.addSendListener(smsListener);

}
```

When I use a debugger I see that the value of `smsCount` is increasing. However, for some reason, it returns zero when I try to access it from outside the class. Is there anything wrong with this code ? `sendMessage` is called whenever an SMS is sent.

Comment: When you access it from outside the class, is this from a different thread?

Comment: Wild guess: Are you calling `startListener` from a static initialiser above where the `smsCount` is declared? (To check, you could remove the `= 0`.)  / Mutable statics are generally a really bad idea.

Comment: @JohnB I am not very sure but yes there is a high possibility

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Nope that's not the case

Comment: Try putting `volatile` on the field and see if that addresses the issue. It is probable you have two thread-local copies of the value.

Comment: Unfortunately @JohnB that doesnt seem to solve the problem :/

Comment: Does your code has custom class loading ?

Comment: @Santosh I am not really sure what that means but it's a blackberry app if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on John B's comment, and to be more specific are you accessing it from a different runtime (application) context? Each runtime context has its own global (and therefore) static namespace. To ensure an object is a global singleton you should use the RuntimeStore.

Comment: Most likely this is what is happening. Maybe he's using an alternate entry point.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem was but I used a persistent object to overcome this problem and it seems to work. Thanks for your attention.